# Unable to get machine position data using Fanuc Focas Library

Tags: c#

I want to get Motor current, temperature and Tool life data
also I am trying to get Position details also but I am getting Error code 2.
I have tried all the possible ways to solve the error but I unable to solve the issue.
please can anyone help me to get out of this

Currently I am working on project to read necessary data from the CNC machine using FOCAS library. I have successfully communicated with controller and I have collected following data

1. Machine Status and Mode
2. Machine Alarms
3. Spindle feed and Speed

I want to get details

1. machine position details
2. Machine drive current, temperature details
3. Tool life details

Comment: Please clarify your specific problem or provide additional details to highlight exactly what you need. As it's currently written, it's hard to tell exactly what you're asking.